# Exit Code 768 from exit call

Tags: python

This simple os.system sleep call returned exit code 786. Where is this coming from and what does this mean?

```
python3 -c 'print("Sleeping"); import os; print("Returned", os.system("sleep 3 && exit 3"))'
Sleeping
Returned 768
```

I have this question, as I was looking at this [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue23750).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't come from "sleep", it came from the "exit 3".  When you return a numeric value like that, it's stored in the high order byte of the return code, like 0x300, which happens to be 768.